# Django -- list_display has no effect

Tags: python, django

This is my code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from bjorncsv.models import *

class BondsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("rowid", "bond_id", "end_d", "intr", "base_i", "type", "start_d", "first_id", "first_pd")

admin.site.register(Bonds)
```

However, on the Admin interface, it's like the class isn't even there. This is the class in question:

```
class Bonds(models.Model):
    rowid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    bond_id = models.TextField(blank=True)
    end_d = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    intr = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    base_i = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.TextField(blank=True)
    start_d = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    first_id = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    first_pd = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'bonds'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to register it **with** your custom model admin

So, change:

```
admin.site.register(Bonds)
```

to

```
admin.site.register(Bonds, BondsAdmin)
```

If you do not specify the second parameter in the `register` call, the default admin interface will be provided, which of course does not have the `list_display` the way you want.

[Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin)

Comment: Woops. Thanks, boys! Sorry for not finding that. I had searched for the list_display problem for quite a while, but forgot to look in the docs. I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to register Admin class ;-)

```
admin.site.register(Bonds, BondsAdmin)
```